# Correct way to pass parameters to rest api - python

Tags: python

I have a [REST API documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSNQFQ_10.1.6/spp/RestApiRef_v1016.pdf?view=kc) on page 97, that gives me the rest api snippet like this below:
[image]

I did exactly the same with python. See below:

```
import requests

base_url = 'https://hostname/api'
session = requests.Session()
headers = {
    'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
    'x-endeavour-sessionid': '23423423werfer23f23rf2'
}

_params = {
    "resourceType": "vm",
    "from": "hlo",
    "filter": {
        [
            {
                "property": "storageProfileName",
                "value":    "testname",
                "op":       "="
            }
        ]
    }
}

_data = f'''{{
    "name": "*",
    "hypervisorType": "vmware"
}}'''

url_unprotectedvm = base_url + '/hypervisor/search'
unprotectedvm_data = session.post(url_unprotectedvm, params=_params, data=_data, headers=headers, verify=False)
print(unprotectedvm_data)
```

But I am getting a `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'` in line `"op": "="`. I did checkout all the unhashable type list posts and tried changing the list to a tuple. But then the API throws 400 bad request. Is this a problem with the API or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: are you trying to use the endpoint from the documentation?

Comment: @Smurphy0000, yes the same. Except using my hostname, ofcourse!

Comment: did you configure that endpoint to accept the request you are sending?

Comment: It is enabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

{} contains the dict not list. you should try removing {} in filters

```
_params = {
    "resourceType": "vm",
    "from": "hlo",
    "filter":
        [
            {
                "property": "storageProfileName",
                "value":    "testname",
                "op":       "="
            }
        ]
    
}
```